# Using multiple Source control folders in a single build definition TFS 2010

Tags: msbuild

In the Workspace tab

Source Control Folder: I am picking only two locations from my entire team project. I do not want to pick the entire team project because it has 20 projects.

I only need two project locations for the build.
$/TeamProject/ABCProj.SVC
$/TeamProject/ABCProj.UI

Build Agent Folder, If i specify the same $(SourceDir) for both the Source control folder locations($/TeamProject/ABCProj.SVC, $/TeamProject/ABCProj.UI)

above, I am unable to save the build definition.

I am getting an error when saving the Build definition
"$(SourceDir) can only be mapped one time in a given workspace"
Can any one please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to map your version control folders to different source directories, for example:

```
$/TeamProject/ABCProj.SVC -> $(SourceDir)/ABCProj.SVC
$/TeamProject/ABCProj.UI  -> $(SourceDir)/ABCProj.UI
```

Alternatively, you can just map `$/TeamProject` to `$(SourceDir)` and cloak all subprojects you don't want to get the sources for.